# Aurelia animations based on events

Tags: javascript, html, aurelia

How do you animate elements in Aurelia based on events? (i.e., touch events in the browser called `touchstart`, `touchmove`, `touchend`)

Let's take the Android Gmail app as an example for this question. You can archive certain messages by swiping a message to the right or left and you can extend the side menu by pressing the hamburger icon in the top left or start swiping on the left edge of the screen. These elements move depending how much you've moved your finger from the begin position. How would you do this in Aurelia?